Can JGIT be configured to show git commands being executed
I'm trying to checkout the latest from a remote branch using JGIT, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working. Was just wondering if JGIT can echo the commands which are being executed. Does the code below look correct?
git.fetch()
  .setRefSpecs("refs/heads/xxx")
  .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(...))
  .call();

git.checkout().setName(branch).addPath(path).call();

I'm trying to execute
git fetch
git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file

Thank you, for your time
